# How to Drag and Select Multiple Items using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Below is the URL I am trying to automate - https://automationintesting.online/

I have a requirement to select dates from this Calender and we need to select a date and drag to the other date. But how can we achieve this with selenium as actions class dows not support this ?

[image]

Comment: Where can we find the date which is to be dragged to the other date?

Answer (score 0):

The following example makes use of Firefox (geckodriver), with a selenium setup on Linux. You can use Chrome as well, you just need to observe the imports, as well as the code after defining the browser:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as Firefox_Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time as t

firefox_options = Firefox_Options()

firefox_options.add_argument("--width=1280")
firefox_options.add_argument("--height=720")

driverService = Service('chromedriver/geckodriver')

browser = webdriver.Firefox(service=driverService, options=firefox_options)
actions = ActionChains(browser)

url = 'https://automationintesting.online/'

browser.get(url) 

booking_button = WebDriverWait(browser, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Book this room']")))
print(booking_button.location_once_scrolled_into_view)
booking_button.click()

first_day = WebDriverWait(browser, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='02']")))
first_day.click()
t.sleep(2)
last_day = WebDriverWait(browser, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='15']")))
last_day.click()
t.sleep(2)
actions.drag_and_drop(first_day, last_day).perform()
```

You probably don't need to click those dates beforehand, I just did it while testing this. It should work without those clicks as well. Also, docs for Selenium can be found at https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/

EDIT: The above code would be for Python: you did not specify the language. In case you want to do it in Java, you do something like below:

```
WebElement draggable = driver.findElement(By.id("draggable"));
WebElement droppable = driver.findElement(By.id("droppable"));
new Actions(driver)
        .dragAndDrop(draggable, droppable)
        .perform();
```